# The function 'setState' isn't defined

Tags: flutter

I am getting the error

```
The function 'setState' isn't defined.
Try importing the library that defines 'setState', correcting the name to the name of an existing function, or defining a function named 'setState'.
```

in my code. I made sure that I'm using a StatefulWidget and was using the right syntax. The code is working on my other pages, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Here's my code that's causing the error..

```
Widget buildPassTextBox() {
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
      left: 40,
      right: 40,
    ),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 3),
          child: TextField(
            obscureText: _isObscure,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              isDense: true,
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
                fontFamily: "DMSans",
              ),
              hintText: 'Enter your Password',
              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                icon:
                    Icon(_isObscure ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(
                    () {
                      _isObscure = !_isObscure;
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set State is only available with StatefulWidgets. So do

```
class MyStfWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyStfWidgetState createState() => _MyStfWidgetState();
}

class _MyStfWidgetState extends State<MyStfWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 40,
        right: 40,
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 3),
            child: TextField(
              obscureText: _isObscure,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                isDense: true,
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontFamily: "DMSans",
                ),
                hintText: 'Enter your Password',
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon:
                  Icon(_isObscure ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(
                          () {
                        _isObscure = !_isObscure;
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Above code is just to explain why SETSTATE is not defined.

But I dont think this is  what you want . My guess though. So pass a callBack which can invoke setState in relevant parent claass.

P.S - It'll be better to use some state management.

```
class MyStfWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyStfWidgetState createState() => _MyStfWidgetState();
}

class _MyStfWidgetState extends State<MyStfWidget> {
  bool _isObscure = false;

  void callSetState() {
    setState(() {
      _isObscure = !_isObscure;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return buildPassTextBox(callSetState, _isObscure);
  }
}

Widget buildPassTextBox(
    void Function() callSetState, bool isObscure) {
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
      left: 40,
      right: 40,
    ),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 3),
          child: TextField(
            obscureText: isObscure,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              isDense: true,
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
                fontFamily: "DMSans",
              ),
              hintText: 'Enter your Password',
              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(isObscure ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off),
                onPressed: () => callSetState(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```